React Native (with Expo) fetch() TypeError: Network request failed on same computer
I cannot fetch anything from my local .NET webAPI (that's running on my computer) while using my react native app (Expo Go) that is "streamed" to my phone. The error I get is: TypeError: Network request failed
I am able to fetch other public test API's like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" with my app.
The backend is also reachable via Postman and browser by every device in the network, when trying to get response from it.
This is my setup:

Computer that has the backend (192.168.8.100:7036) web API running AND the Expo Go (192.168.8.100:8081) server running.
Phone that displays the app while being connected to the Expo Go server via Expo Go app.
Every device is in the same network.


Figured a workaround. Not sure 100% but the issue could've been caused by having my mobile app running localy trying to reach an api call on the same local server (just like engr.ukairo suggested earlier). Even calling directly by ip didn't work.
I decided to try ngrok and it works. Worth it and doesn't take alot of time to configure.

Your react native app cannot connect to your local server just like a web app or your postman app. To connect to your local server, use http://10.0.2.2:7036 instead of http://192.168.8.100:7036 for your API connection url.

We had a similar issue. My colleague explained that by default, Android/Expo Go does not allow API calls over HTTP. That's why it functions as you said by using ngrok.
I think, you still can use HTTP but you need to configure manually it in xml file about restriction.

Your answer should be a comment on the answer that mentions ngrok. You can copy and delete your answer and paste it in as a comment.
